# SIGABRT between loadView and viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, uiviewcontroller, sigabrt

I'm new to iOS development, and having trouble identifying the source of a `SIGABRT`.  I've narrowed it down to something that happens during initialization of a `UIViewController` subclass, specifically between its `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` methods.

I narrowed it down with an `NSLog` call in each of those method overloads in my `UIViewController` subclass.  However, I'm unable to get any more granularity from the debugger; I can't step into the `[super loadView]` method.  Are there any techniques for debugging a SIGABRT other than NSLogs and stepping through with the debugger?  Is there any way to see exactly from where the exception was thrown?

**Program-specific details**

This program uses Core Data; I created it following [this tutorial](http://timroadley.com/2012/02/19/core-data-basics-part-4-relationships/).  I believe the SIGABRT started happening after I ran through the "Relationships In Action" section, and was not happening before (I *think* I had a successful build at the end of the preceding section).  Specifically, I can successfully add a Person, but `PersonDetailTableViewController` throws a SIGABRT between `loadView` and `viewDidLoad`.

I've tried deleting the app from the iPhone simulator, and also running a Product > Clean; neither had any effect.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint on all exceptions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844725/why-does-nsassert-break-in-main-instead-of-in-the-code-that-call-the-assertion/10845508#10845508

Comment: hm, well, now it just stops on the [super loadView] call.  i'm thinking i may have something set up incorrectly in my storyboard, but i've scoured it and nothing's popping out at me.

Comment: Possibly you have an incorrect class name in your storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit.  I had earlier incorrectly created an IBOutlet by ctrl+dragging from a `Table View Cell`'s `Text Field` into my `UITableViewController` subclass.  I manually deleted the code this created, but a connection remained in the Connections Inspector.  Deleting that connection solved the problem -- no more SIGABRT.

It's unfortunate that Xcode sees the problem (see the exclamation mark in the attached image), but didn't tell me about it in any way except the mysterious SIGABRT....

[image: Connections inspector shows invalid connection]